# Typescript error using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, typescript

I'm using node.js with typescript@1.7.5, express@4.13.3, mongoose@4.3.7 and mongodb@3.2.0

I get compile error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '(error: any, document: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any) => void'.

at the line: `(error, document) => {`

Everything works fine at runtime even with this compile error.
How can I solve this error?

```
import express = require("express");
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import mongoose = require("mongoose");

import contactListModel = require("./contactlistSchema");
var contact = contactListModel.contact;

export function removeOne (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log("delete one contact in database with id: " + id);
    contact.remove(
        {_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)},
        (error, document) => {
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            } else {
                console.log(document)
                res.jsonp(document);
            }
        }
    )
}
```

**contactlistSchema.ts**

```
import mongoose = require("mongoose");

export var contactlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    number: String,
    type: String

});

export interface IContactList extends mongoose.Document{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    number: string;
    type: string

}

export var contact = mongoose.model<IContactList>("contact", contactlistSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because [`Model.remove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) doesn't provide the removed doc to the callback.

So the code will still run, but `document` will be `undefined` in your callback.

To resolve the error, just remove the `document` parameter from your callback:

```
contact.remove(
    {_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)},
    (error) => {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
            res.jsonp({success: true});
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Also keep in mind the typings are for Mongoose v3 but you're using Mongoose v4.

Comment: Thanks for your response.   
This gives another error:   
`TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`   
On the line: `res.jsonp();`

Comment: @HermanFransen You would pass whatever response data you want to return as a parameter to the `res.jsonp` call. e.g. `res.jsonp({success: true})`.

Comment: If I keep it the way it was, then I get an object returned: {ok: 1, n: 1}. So I guess that the `res.jsonp(document);` does it ok. So nothing is wrong with the coding I guess. And maybe @Harangue is right that the typings I am using are for mongoose v3 while I am using v4.

Comment: @HermanFransen It's basically a problem of undocumented behavior. The typings file is in agreement with the Mongoose docs, but there's an undocumented second parameter passed to the callback from the underlying driver.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I see now you are right about this. You are more experienced than I am, what would you do? Ignore the compile error or adjust the code the way you suggested?

Comment: @HermanFransen I definitely wouldn't recommend just ignoring the warning. You can either: 1) stop using the second parameter; 2) submit a pull request to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped that fixes the definition of that `remove` method to define the contents of the second parameter; 3) cast your callback method to the matching type.